# how many bridge hands have the king of spades and at least one diamond?

Tags: combinations

I think the answer is :C(51,12)-C(38,12).Since one card is fixed in this 13 cards.I just need to choose 12 cards from 52-1=51 cards.And rather than listing all the possibilities of choosing at least 1 diamond,I choose it in the opposite way.That is ,assuming that no diamonds are in the 12 cards.In this case, I choose 12 cards from 51-13=38(exclude all the diamonds) and it gives C(38,12).At last, I just need to subtract C(38,12) from C(51,12) .Is that correct?

Comment: Nicely reasoned.

Comment: Check out [this site](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286519/how-many-bridge-hands-have-the-king-of-spades-and-at-least-one-diamond) or [this site](http://www.bridgehands.com/P/Probability_of_Card_Distribution.htm). IIRC they give sound looking data about bridge related distributions and their probabilities.